Reedy cofibration category structure

Is there a notion of Reedy cofibration category written down somewhere
? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Motivation: I ask the question because I have a cofibration category in the sense of https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cofibration+category and I need to consider the diagrams in this cofibration category over the direct Reedy category $0\to 1 \to 2 \to \dots$. And I need the fact that the colimit functor is a left Quillen adjoint somehow. Does it make sense for a cofibration category ?

I’m pretty sure this is done; off the top of my head I don’t remember where, but it should be mentioned in the bibliography of my paper with Chris Kapulkin Homotopical inverse diagrams in CwA’s.  Possibly it’s in work of Kapulkin and/or Szumilo?  I don’t have time to search it up now, but can try later if someone else doesn’t find a good source sooner!

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Indeed, it's Theorem 9.2.4 of Cofibrations in Homotopy Theory.
